# Icone do Stack Overflow em Português

Tags: debate

Futuramente este ícone irá se diferenciar do Stack Overflow normal?

Quando clico no ícone da barra para ver minha reputação aparece desta forma.

[image: icones]

Fica muito confuso com ícones iguais. Não sou designer, mas uma ideia:

[image: sugestão icone]

Ou algo assim, seria bom para diferenciar.

Comment: Se quer sugerir como deve ficar, poderia ser na outra questão: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/22/mudar-favicon-para-torna-lo-um-pouco-distinto-do-usado-no-stackoverflow-em-ingle

Comment: O time de design já tá ciente